# Problem while accessing object in array with template language

Tags: django

```
{% for number in appliers|length|times %} 
  {% if connector|get_by_index:number == commission.id %} 
     {{appliers|get_by_index:number}} 
  {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

I have made custom_template filter and it have worked great but the problem is that i can't access `appliers[number]'s` class variables.

I tried accessing by `{{appliers|get_by_index:number.email}}` and it wouldn't work... please can any one can tell me  how to solve this?

Comment: What is `times`? do you really need the number or is there a better way to achieve whatever you're trying to do

Comment: @register.filter(name='times') 
def times(number):
    return range(number)

Comment: So if thats just returning a range then do you not just need to zip together the `appliers and connector` in the view? then you'll just be able to get the `applier` and `connector` without needing the index